# Upload large file to azure storage and link it in Drupal

Tags: 7, files

I have some large Files (>3GB) to upload to a Drupal (running on azure). Because of the size of the files, I think i need to upload it to the azure storage (with Azure Storage Explorer) and then use the file in Drupal. This all works fine so far.

But: When I create the content page, I can't find a way to browse the azure storage instead of the local File system?

I use Windows Azure Integration. But this just gives me the possibility to upload a file to a azure storage blob. When I try this with a large File in the Drupal installation, it takes forever (ok, I didn't wait until the end). I am looking for the other way around: upload file to azure storage. Use this file in Drupal.

Does anyone have a solution? Or how would you solve the problem?

---

Using the proposed Remote File Source worked for me when I choose "File Attach". I have to upload the file to the web-server though and not to the azure storage. But doing this with filezilla does the job.

Comment: [Windows Azure Integration](https://drupal.org/project/azure) does not work for you? I don't know Azure, to be honest, but you haven't mentioned the most obvious module at all. Even note "it does not provide this functionality" would help us see you have tried what you could :)

Comment: How are you "browsing the local File system" at the moment? Do you mean using the standard browser "Upload" button?

Comment: hi Molot :-) sorry, yes, I use Windows Azure Integration. But this just gives me the possibility to upload a file to a azure storage blob. When I try this with a large File in the drupal installation, it seems to take forever (ok, I didn't wait until the end). I am looking for the other way around: upload file to azure storage. Use this file in Drupal.

Comment: Hi Clive, yes, so far I can only browse the local File system using the standard upload button. I would like to have a possibility to browse the azure storage blob.

Comment: Hello. Please use @ in front of our names if you want us to get notified you replied. And edit your comment to me into your question, as this information puts you into a better light ;) and allows to provide answers that will not repeat what you tried and found not working.

Comment: @Molot learning a bit every day :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the [Remote File Source](https://drupal.org/project/remote_file_source) module?

> Remote File Source allows you to add a file from a remote server to a filefield without transferring it locally.

I haven't tried it, but it looks stable with only a couple of bugs

Comment: When I try remote File I get the following error: Unable to fetch file from Remote File URL https://...zip (error 505: The HTTP version specified is not supported for this operation by the server.).

Comment: Might be this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883401/why-505-http-version-not-supported-on-public-wifi. Not sure though I'm afraid, my knowledge of Azure hosting is basically nothing. I know a 505 is a mismatch in the HTTP protocol version between client and server though, so that'll be where to start looking

Comment: when i use "File Attach" it works. I have to upload the file to the web-server though and not to the azure storage. But doing this with filezilla does the job.